# How can I export a list of pipelines from Azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am relatively new to Azure DevOps. I am documenting the pipelines that currently exist within Azure DevOps and there are hundreds of them. Is there a way to export the names of all of the pipelines and potentially any other information about them (like pipeline description or environment) into an excel or something similar? I have read only access. I have not been able to figure out an easy way to do this and I feel like there must be a better solution than manually copying them one by one.

I've looked through questions on stack overflow but none seemed to answer this specific question.

Comment: see all the az pipeline commands, and specifically  az pipeline list,   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-list

Answer (score 1):

### REST

Depending on the technology you want to use you can use the for example the REST api of Azure DevOps, for YAML pipelines:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

For the classic pipelines:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

### PowerShell

Or using PowerShell with VSTeam, check out the Getting started [here](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/overview/getting-started).

For (YAML) build:

https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Get-VSTeamBuildDefinition

`Get-VSTeamBuildDefinition -ProjectName Demo | Format-List *`

And Classic (release) pipelines:

https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition

`Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition -ProjectName demo | Format-List *`

This result can than easily opened into Excel with `$obj | Export-Excel` :
https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, REST API is a good approach.

To get all the pipelines from a DevOps Project, you could use: [Pipeline-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

This could list all pipelines including pipeline name and pipeline ID.

[image]

You could copy the output into an excel and filter your target info.

[image]

With the above pipeline ID, you could use this REST API: [Pipelines-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to retrieve more info related to this specific pipeline by ID.

Variables:

[image]

Repo info:

[image]

Environments related API are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)